# `ROS_INFO_STREAM_NAMED(name, msg)` isn't streaming to the appropriate name

Tags: ros, logger, rosconsole, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Lets say I have these names: "A", "B", "C"

There is a weird case where I use `ROS_INFO_STREAM_NAMED(name, msg)` and it streams the message to "A", even though the variable name is "B" or "C". However, when I hard code the name in: `if (name == "B") ROS_INFO_STREAM_NAMED(name, msg)` or `ROS_INFO_STREAM_NAMED("B", msg)` then it works.

I am callling `ROS_INFO_STREAM_NAMED(name, msg)` in my own `log` function which is located in a c++ interface. Classes A, B, and C all extends said interface and thus has access to `log`. Every ros spin cycle I would call on A's read function which calls on B's read function, which calls on C's read function. in each of these read functions, they would just `log("reading")`. But when I try to filter them out by name using `rqt_logger_level`, `ros.<my package>.A` would control the levels for what is suppose to be B and C's messages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222747/%60ros_info_stream_named(name,-msg)%60-isn%27t-streaming-to-the-appropriate-name/) by [C-Dog](https://answers.ros.org/users/25362/c-dog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-12-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-18**:
I think it would help if you included the sources you are referring to. Could you edit your question and add some snippets (be sure to format them using the *Preformatted text* button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually I found the answer to my question here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/561

---

Originally posted by [C-Dog](https://answers.ros.org/users/25362/c-dog/) with karma: 36 on 2015-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, I assume you are using a `ROS_INFO_STREAM_NAMED`, right? Otherwise, the question would make no sense.

Have a look at [the documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging) on the ROS wiki.
Especiallly this part:

> **Do not use a variable with changing value as the name**
>
> Each named logger is stored in a static variable which is initialized on the use of the macro. Either use a string or a
> variable which string value is not going to change for future invocations since they won't be affecting the logger
> anymore.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-12-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [C-Dog](https://answers.ros.org/users/25362/c-dog/) on 2015-12-18**:
So if I were to use a variable as the name, would I have to make it a constant string? As 8n the example before, can I have a const string in each class (A, B, C) that can be referenced later to log to the appropriate name?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-12-18**:
Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand you correctly.
However, as I understand the documentation, the variable you pass to the macro should be const, if this is what you are asking...

**Comment by [C-Dog](https://answers.ros.org/users/25362/c-dog/) on 2015-12-18**:
You are right, but I was just trying to think of a way to achieve what this person was trying to make:https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/561